# Съезжает выравнивание таблицы вопросов/ответов в профиле

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн

Из-за недостаточной ширины поля, выделенного для времени, происходит сдвиг при отображении таблицы вопросов/ответов на странице профиля:

> [image: таблица ответов]

Конечно, проблему снова можно решить путём предоставления более короткого перевода. Но это всё будет полумерами до тех пор, пока для локализованных версий Stack Overflow не будет предоставлена возможность задавать размеры необходимых полей независимо от основного (англоязычного) сайта.